# File location of compiled iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, packaging, dmg

I'm writing an iPhone app in simulator/debug mode at the moment. I'd like to know, after I build it, where does the binary go? I want to send this file to my friend to show him what I'm doing so far.

Also, how do I package apps into .dmg files? That seems to be the better format to send app to other people?

Comment: How would you be able to send an iPhone app to someone in a DMG file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you joined the iPhone Developer Program?
If so you will need your friend's device ID to generate a provisioning profile.
I recommend that you read [Publishing Applications for Testing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Publishing_Applications_for_Testing/user_testing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW2) for more details.

Your binary files will be on {Project Folder}/build/, there you will have one directory for each of the possible options: Release/Debug and iphoneos/iphoneSimulator.

To create the DMG read [Creating a .DMG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367751/creating-a-dmg).

Answer (score 1):

by default, the built results are located in `{Project Folder}/build/Debug` (or Release if you build in that config). You can use the `hdiutil` command-line tool to generate a DMG of your app - have a look at its man page which is quite comprehensive.

Comment: How come when I open /build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app it just crashes? Yet I can build and run from Xcode.