# How to create a temporary directory?

Tags: bash, temporary-directory

I used to create a `tempfile`, delete it and recreate it as a directory:

```
temp=`tempfile`
rm -f $temp
  # <breakpoint>
mkdir $temp
```

The problem is, when it runs to the *<breakpoint>*, there happens to be another program that wants to do the same thing, which *mkdir*-ed a temp dir with the same name, will cause the failure of this program.

How should I make a temp directory instead of a file?

Comment: Git Bash for Windows does not have `tempfile`, but it does have `mktemp`.

Answer (score 469, accepted):

Use [`mktemp -d`](http://www.mktemp.org/). It creates a temporary directory with a random name and makes sure that file doesn't already exist. You need to remember to delete the directory after using it though.

Comment: I had to use `mktemp -d -t <prefix>`

Comment: This is a OS X vs Linux thing.  See this question for a version that works on both:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30091/fix-or-alternative-for-mktemp-in-os-x

Comment: Also, see the answer below by Ortwin, as that makes sure cleanup is done as well.

Comment: Why do you say "You need to remember to delete the directory after using it though."? Doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose of using a temp directory?

Comment: @M.K.Safi I think the main purpose is to create an empty directory where you can store temporary files without cluttering up other parts of the filesystem.  You get to choose if/when you want to delete it.  If it creates it in /tmp, then it should be cleared when the system restarts anyway.

Comment: @mwfearnley "... it should be cleared when the system restarts anyway", true, though that could be weeks, months or even years away - best clean-up to avoid space/clutter issues

Comment: @Straff fair enough, and it's worth saying that some environments like WSL may never automatically clear out /tmp/, but my point was just that even if you need to delete it afterwards, it doesn't undermine the whole purpose of it.

Answer (score 113):

For a more robust solution i use something like the following. That way the temp dir will always be deleted after the script exits.

The cleanup function is executed on the `EXIT` signal. That guarantees that the cleanup function is always called, even if the script aborts somewhere.

```
#!/bin/bash    

# the directory of the script
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# the temp directory used, within $DIR
# omit the -p parameter to create a temporal directory in the default location
WORK_DIR=`mktemp -d -p "$DIR"`

# check if tmp dir was created
if [[ ! "$WORK_DIR" || ! -d "$WORK_DIR" ]]; then
  echo "Could not create temp dir"
  exit 1
fi

# deletes the temp directory
function cleanup {      
  rm -rf "$WORK_DIR"
  echo "Deleted temp working directory $WORK_DIR"
}

# register the cleanup function to be called on the EXIT signal
trap cleanup EXIT

# implementation of script starts here
...
```

Directory of bash script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/540286%20here).

Bash [traps](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html).

Comment: **FreeBSD Caution!** mktemp on FreeBSD doesn't have -p option, and `cleanup` will **rm -rf your current directory!**

Comment: Good point, updated the script to check if the temp dir could be created.

Comment: @madfriend really? if `mktemp` fails, `WORK_DIR` will be empty, meaning the command would just be `rm -rf` with no argument. I don't use FreeBSD but I'd be pretty surprised if `rm -rf` was equivalent to `rm -rf .`

Comment: @jbg yes, it seems odd to me now too - it shouldn't be a really big problem. I might have tweaked an old version of this script so that a path to temporary directory was calculated relatively to current directory, resulting in <s>extinction of mankind</s> current directory removal.

Comment: I'll give you a -1 for safety reasons with that **rm -rf** thing and the trap, sorry. You are too worried in deleting a temporary directory. Not worth the risk you are causing.

Comment: @DrBeco it all depends on the use case. We use it a lot in build scripts and it works just fine there. And yes i am worried about the temp files on our build server.

Comment: To make it better, you can avoid an empty directory or at least contain the problem within a directory using a solution where you do: 1. `TMPWORKDIR=$(basename 'mktemp -d -p /tmp/git/')` and then 2. `rmdir /tmp/git/"${TMPWORKDIR}"`. If the variable is empty now, you will still fall back to `/tmp/git/` not to the whole system. Consider something like this in the answer and I'll gladly agree. ;)

Comment: @DrBeco I was about to ask the same, why use current dir of script when there's the `/tmp` dir you could use. Also one level deeper, your '/tmp/git` will prevent falling back to `/tmp` accidentally and potentially force-removing files still in use by others.

Comment: @DrBeco the script will exit if the variable is empty before reaching the trap, or do i miss something?

Comment: @Davos we use it to keep the logs/files/whatever close to the test case. It is/can be bothersome to find logs. (use `trap - EXIT´ to disable the trap if eg. a test failes)

Comment: @OrtwinAngermeier I guess that makes sense, but wouldn't the logs be deleted when it exits? That would make them * really * hard to find.

Answer (score 84):

My favorite one-liner for this is

```
cd $(mktemp -d)
```

Comment: and ``rm $(pwd)``? :P

Comment: also useful: `pushd $(mktemp -d)` ... `popd`

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell should be `rm -r $(pwd)`

Comment: Depending on what you put in the temp directory, you might might need `rm -rf $(pwd)` to remove it.

Comment: @piggybox Frankly, I'd be *very* cautious of using `rm -r $(pwd)`.  Consider the possibility that temporary directory creation fails for whatever reason (maybe the /tmp filesystem is full or has been remounted read only due to an error?); then `cd $(mktemp -d)` will evaluate to `cd` which changes to the user's home directory, which would subsequently be deleted.

Comment: It may be safe with `if pushd $(mktemp -d || echo BADMPDIR); then ........ ; rm -r $(pwd); popd; fi`

Comment: For _bash_, the current working dir (pwd) changed in the parentheses will be restored outside the parentheses. So a convenient way is: `tmp=$(mktemp -d); (cd $tmp; ...)`

Answer (score 23):

The following snippet will safely create and then clean up a temporary directory.

The first `trap` line executes `exit 1` command when any of the specified signals is received. The second `trap` line removes the `$TEMPD` on program's exit (both normal and abnormal). We initialize these traps after we check that `mkdir -d` succeeded to avoid accidentally executing the exit trap with `$TEMPD` in an unknown state.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# set -x # un-comment to see what's going on when you run the script

# Create a temporary directory and store its name in a variable.
TEMPD=$(mktemp -d)

# Exit if the temp directory wasn't created successfully.
if [ ! -e "$TEMPD" ]; then
    >&2 echo "Failed to create temp directory"
    exit 1
fi

# Make sure the temp directory gets removed on script exit.
trap "exit 1"           HUP INT PIPE QUIT TERM
trap 'rm -rf "$TEMPD"'  EXIT
```

Comment: While this is an interesting solution for the error handling, a bit more explanation of the advantages and possible shortcomings would be nice.

Comment: 1.) `-d` checks for directories. 2.) Termination is already the default for those signals.

Comment: Don't suggest TMPDIR as variable name here, as that is typically the system's temporary directory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR

Comment: Thanks @spawn, I renamed the TMPDIR variable.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple explanation about how to create a temp dir using templates.

1. Creates  a temporary file or directory, safely, and prints its name.
2. TEMPLATE must contain at least 3 consecutive 'X's in last component.
3. If TEMPLATE is not specified, it will use tmp.XXXXXXXXXX
4. directories created are u+rwx, minus umask restrictions.

```sh
PARENT_DIR=./temp_dirs # (optional) specify a dir for your tempdirs
mkdir $PARENT_DIR

TEMPLATE_PREFIX='tmp' # prefix of your new tempdir template
TEMPLATE_RANDOM='XXXX' # Increase the Xs for more random characters
TEMPLATE=${PARENT_DIR}/${TEMPLATE_PREFIX}.${TEMPLATE_RANDOM}

# create the tempdir using your custom $TEMPLATE, which may include
# a path such as a parent dir, and assign the new path to a var
NEW_TEMP_DIR_PATH=$(mktemp -d $TEMPLATE)
echo $NEW_TEMP_DIR_PATH

# create the tempdir in parent dir, using default template
# 'tmp.XXXXXXXXXX' and assign the new path to a var
NEW_TEMP_DIR_PATH=$(mktemp -p $PARENT_DIR)
echo $NEW_TEMP_DIR_PATH

# create a tempdir in your systems default tmp path e.g. /tmp 
# using the default template 'tmp.XXXXXXXXXX' and assign path to var
NEW_TEMP_DIR_PATH=$(mktemp -d)
echo $NEW_TEMP_DIR_PATH

# Do whatever you want with your generated temp dir and var holding its path
```

Answer (score 3):

I need the following features:

- Put all temp files into a single directory with a specific namespace for reusing.
- Create temp files with filename prefix and suffix (extension).

With `bash` script on macOS:

```bash
$ namespace="com.namespace.mktemp"

# find directory for reusing
$ ls -d "${TMPDIR}${namespace}"*

# create directory if not exists
$ mktemp -d -t "$namespace"
/var/folders/s_/.../T/com.namespace.mktemp.HjqGT6w2

# create tempfile with directory name and file prefix
$ mktemp -t "com.namespace.mktemp.HjqGT6w2/file-prefix"
/var/folders/s_/.../T/com.namespace.mktemp.HjqGT6w2/file-prefix.sZDvjo14

# add suffix - `mktemp` on macOS does not support `--suffix`
mv "/var/folders/s_/.../file-prefix.sZDvjo14" "/var/folders/s_/.../file-prefix.sZDvjo14.txt"
```

The `gmktemp` (`brew install coreutils`) is a little different:

- supports `--suffix` and `--tmpdir`
- Xs are required in `template` and `prefix`
- `template` should not contain directory, set `TMPDIR` instead

```bash
$ namespace="com.namespace.gmktemp"

# create directory if not exists
$ gmktemp -d -t "$namespace.XXXXXXXX"
/var/folders/s_/.../T/com.namespace.gmktemp.BjFtIAyZ

# set TMPDIR
TMPDIR="/var/folders/s_/.../T/com.namespace.gmktemp.BjFtIAyZ"

# create tempfile with directory name and file prefix
$ gmktemp --suffix=".txt" -t "prefix.XXXXXXXX"
/var/folders/s_/.../T/com.namespace.gmktemp.BjFtIAyZ/prefix.LWHj0G95.txt
```